# how to return info from UI elements into thread

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps

I've created an app with a GoogleMap.
I want to do some maths and update the GoogleMap's markers inside a thread that runs all the time.

My thread needs to know the current googleMap's camera zoom and also the LatLngBounds to update the markers.

If I do that it works perfectly:

```
class updateMap implements Runnable{
    private double currentZoom;
    private LatLngBounds screenRegion;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!threadStop){//threadStop is a boolean to stop threads when onDestroy() is called
                screenRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;//fetches the screen's visible region
                currentZoom = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
            if(googleMap != null){//if my googleMap is fine
                if(currentZoom >= 13){ //if the Camera's zoom is greater or equal than 13
                    //do some maths...
                    //updates the markers on the GoogleMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I know it's not recommended to interact with the UI thread directly within the thread so I've put the few lines of code that interact with the UI thread inside the method runOnUiThread() as followed but it doesn't work. My app freezes and nothing happens, ARN doesn't even show up !

```
class updateMap implements Runnable{
    private double currentZoom;
    private LatLngBounds screenRegion;
    boolean map = false;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!threadStop){//threadStop is a boolean to stop threads when onDestroy() is called
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {//Here I execute this piece of code on the UI thread to get the variables
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(googleMap != null){
                        map = true;
                        screenRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;//fetches the screen's visible region
                        currentZoom = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(map){//if my googleMap is fine
                if(currentZoom >= 13){ //if the Camera's zoom is greater or equal than 13
                    //do some maths...
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            //updates the markers on the GoogleMap
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea ? Maybe I don't respect the syntax or maybe I shouldn't use the runOnUiThread() method twice or something...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the math you are doing time-consuming?

Comment: No, there are only a couple loops to check if the items I wanna add on the map are within the viewable region of the map.

Answer (score -1):

I think using UI thread to get data is wrong in your case. Do it before separate thread start and pass as parameters.

Comment: that would be a solution but I need to know the map's current zoom all the time. Each time my loop is starting over, I have to check if the zoom is actually greater or equal to 13.